# Replace content of Div with content of another div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to replace the content of a div with the contents of another div (which is hidden using css) by clicking on an image. However using a few methods suggested on here I can't seem to get it working.

my code is below:

html

```
<h3>Recent Callaborations</h3>
    <div id="collaborations">
    <img class="rec1" src="http://domain.com/michaelscott/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/url.png"/>
    <div id="rec1">Some image caption that is hidden now and that will replace what is in the rec div below</div>
 </div>

<div id="rec-box" class="rec">
    this is the content that is to be replaced
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".rec1").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault() 
            jQuery('#rec-box').html($(this).next('#rec1')[0].outerHTML); 
          });
        });
```

css

```
#collaborations {
    width: 100%;    
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
}

#collaborations img {
    display:inline-block;
}
.rec {
    background: #EDEDED;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
#rec1, #rec2, #rec3, #rec4 {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to set the `html()` of the correct `div`. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".rec1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault() 
        jQuery('#rec-box').html(jQuery(this).next().html()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".rec1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault() 
        jQuery('#rec-box').html(jQuery("#rec1").html()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code seems to fail because you capture the entire hidden element, rather than just its contents, by using the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) property (rather than [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)). This means the newly copied content still has `<div id='rec1'...>`, and is still hidden as a result of the css rule.

jQuery's `html` method can both get and set `innerHTML`, so that's the correct method here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".rec1").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#rec-box').html($('#rec1').html()); //replaces with contents of #rec1
  });
});
```

Comment: P.S. `$` is shorthand for `jQuery`, and is generally easier to read, so use that unless you have a naming conflict (i.e. unless some other library is already using `$`)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the following solution :) Hope it helps

**HTML**

```
<h3>Recent Callaborations</h3>
<div id="collaborations">
    <a href="#rec1" class="switchContent"><img class="rec1" src="http://cmagics.eu/michaelscott/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/url.png"/></a>
    <div id="rec1">Some image caption that is hidden now and that will replace what is in the rec div below</div>
 </div>

<div id="rec-box" class="rec">
    this is the content that is to be replaced
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    switchContent   =   function(ev) {
        var el  =   $($(this).attr('href'));
        if(el.length == 1) {
            $('#rec-box').html(el.html());
        }
        ev.preventDefault();
    };

    $('.switchContent').on('click',switchContent);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `$("#rec").contents()` and `.clone()` it

You need to `.append()` it in `$('#rect-box')` after having `.empty()` it

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".rec1").on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#rec-box').empty().append(($('#rec1').contents().clone());
    });
});
```