# Replace Div Content onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know nothing about jQuery but want to achieve something really important.

I want to have a button/link that will replace the div content and if I press that button again so it will put the original content back in position.

Comment: Please post some code and what have you tried so far...

Comment: I don't know javascript that's why I didn't code. I found one stackoverflow problem near to my need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685224/replace-content-of-div-with-content-of-another-div-jquery

Comment: I put this in JS fiddle and change some code, it's working but I don't know how to put the original content back if I click the link again.

Comment: Here's my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/junaidkhawaja/vmu0gtoL/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="1">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#btnClick').on('click',function(){
    if($('#1').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#2').html('Here is my dynamic content').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
    }
});
```

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/
http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/4 <--- Commented

Comment: Thanks. Your fiddle is near to my help. You put 'here is my dynamic content' in JS but I need a HTML div that will show and replace on click.. can you help me out to tweak your fiddle...

Comment: yeah, that one is perfect.. I saw you set onload for that, how I will be inserting that code in my Wordpress website. Another silly question.. I don't know how to make 4 codes like this.. can you do that in that fiddle.. Help will be appreciated ..

Comment: @JunaidKhawaja, you got try to understand it, I won't do it for you, but I'll explain to you the code, if you want.

Comment: You're right. I put the code thrice and changed the IDs but it got some errors.. Let me do it myself... Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm gonna add some help for you in my answer, just a minute.

Comment: It will be appreciable!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/4/ here's the code commented, I've tried to make it clear, if you have any questions tell me, note that you can use events on any elements, like, if you replace btnClick with a div ID, it will work aswell, when it detects a click on the div.

Comment: Thank you master! I came up with solution with your help.. Here's what I needed. http://jsfiddle.net/junaidkhawaja/ha6qp7w4/5/

Comment: @JunaidKhawaja, seems like you got it :DD

Comment: Yeah, Just because of your help !

Comment: Is there anyway that one div can be displayed by default? And then you can click the other div and that will display. At the minute, you have to click to see any content at all.

Answer (score 3):

A simple addClass and removeClass will do the trick on what you need..

```
$('#change').on('click', function() { 
  $('div').each(function() { 
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) { 
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else { 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

});

Seee [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/c2oa7r2g/)

I recommend you to learn jquery first before using.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  This answer was submitted before the OP's jsFiddle example was posted in question. See second answer for response to that jsFiddle.

---

Here is an example of how it could work:

<kbd>[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLtbkego/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="someDiv">
    Once upon a midnight dreary
    <br>While I pondered weak and weary
    <br>Over many a quaint and curious
    <br>Volume of forgotten lore.
</div>
Type new text here:<br>
<input type="text" id="replacementtext" />
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Swap" />

<input type="hidden" id="vault" />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
//Declare persistent vars outside function
var savText, newText, myState = 0;

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    if (myState==0){
        savText = $('#someDiv').html(); //save poem data from DIV
        newText = $('#replacementtext').val(); //save data from input field
        $('#replacementtext').val(''); //clear input field
        $('#someDiv').html( newText ); //replace poem with insert field data
        myState = 1; //remember swap has been done once
    } else {
        $('#someDiv').html(savText);
        $('#replacementtext').val(newText); //replace contents
        myState = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working from your jsFiddle example:**

The jsFiddle was fine, but you were missing semi-colons at the end of the event.preventDefault() statements.

This works: [**Revised jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0gtoL/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".rec1").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#rec-box').html(jQuery(this).next().html()); 
    });
    jQuery(".rec2").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#rec-box2').html(jQuery(this).next().html()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: no, I need something else that is defined in BernardoLima comments.. see comments over there.. I need more help but I think he is offline..

Answer (score 1):

**A Third Answer**

Sorry, maybe I have it correct *this* time...

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0gtoL/3/)</kbd>

```
var savedBox1, savedBox2, state1=0, state2=0;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".rec1").click(function() {
        if (state1==0){
            savedBox1 = jQuery('#rec-box').html();
            jQuery('#rec-box').html(jQuery(this).next().html()); 
            state1 = 1;
        }else{
            jQuery('#rec-box').html(savedBox1); 
            state1 = 0;
        }
    });

    jQuery(".rec2").click(function() {
        if (state1==0){
            savedBox2 = jQuery('#rec-box2').html();
            jQuery('#rec-box2').html(jQuery(this).next().html()); 
            state2 = 1;
        }else{
            jQuery('#rec-box2').html(savedBox2); 
            state2 = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

> I think that you want something like this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#btnClick').on('click',function(){
if($('#1').css('display')!='none'){
$('#2').show().siblings('div').hide();
}else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
}
});
```

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ha6qp7w4/1113/  <--- see this I hope You want something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **complete solution** in order to achieve this -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function toggleText(){
    if ($("#txt-1").css("display") != "none") {
        $("#txt-1").css("display", "none");
        $("#txt-2").css("display", "block");
        $("#txt-3").css("display", "none");
    } else if ($("#txt-2").css("display") != "none") {
        $("#txt-1").css("display", "none");
        $("#txt-2").css("display", "none");
        $("#txt-3").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $("#txt-1").css("display", "block");
        $("#txt-2").css("display", "none");
        $("#txt-3").css("display", "none");
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleText()">Toggle</button>

<p id="txt-1">Hello</p>
<p id="txt-2" style="display: none;">How are you?</p>
<p id="txt-3" style="display: none;">See you soon!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]