# Want to change div when click rounded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can You help me with this obstacle please.

I have this site [here](http://promotii-timisoara.com/magicmarketing) and I want my red div to change when i click an rounded image.

I have copied the code from another website i have!

Here is the code for the section:

```
<div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu79"><!-- group -->
 <div class="browser_width grpelem" id="u79"><!-- group -->
  <div class="clearfix" id="u79_align_to_page">
   <a class="anchor_item grpelem" id="band"></a>
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u80-4"><!-- content -->

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="PamphletWidget clearfix grpelem" id="pamphletu323"><!-- none box -->
  <div class="ThumbGroup clearfix grpelem" id="u324"><!-- none box -->
   <div class="popup_anchor">
    <div class="Thumb popup_element rounded-corners" id="u325"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   </div>
   <div class="popup_anchor">
    <div class="Thumb popup_element rounded-corners" id="u379"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   </div>
   <div class="popup_anchor">
    <div class="Thumb popup_element rounded-corners" id="u388"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   </div>
   <div class="popup_anchor">
    <div class="Thumb popup_element rounded-corners" id="u390"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   </div>
   <div class="popup_anchor">
    <div class="Thumb popup_element rounded-corners" id="u3911"><!-- simple frame --></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup_anchor" id="u328popup">
   <div class="ContainerGroup clearfix" id="u328"><!-- stack box -->
    <div class="Container clearfix grpelem" id="u330"><!-- group -->
     <div class="museBGSize grpelem" id="u348"><!-- simple frame --></div>
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu355-4"><!-- column -->
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u355-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>LORENZO-CRISTIAN</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u357-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>MAGICIAN-ILUZIONIST</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u356-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>Izvorul Inepuizabil de creatie artistica,  omul care mereu viseaza, planifica si duce visele la indeplinire.<br/>Realizatorul spectacolului, iluziilor si efectelor speciale…  </br/>The Master!</p>
      </div>
                            <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:-300px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/MagicianulLorenzoCristian?ref=hl"><div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u1044"><!-- simple frame --></div></a>

      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu358"><!-- group -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Container invi clearfix grpelem" id="u380"><!-- group -->
     <div class="museBGSize grpelem" id="u392"><!-- simple frame --></div>
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu393-4"><!-- column -->
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u393-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>ANGELINA</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u395-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>ASISTENTA</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u394-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>Arta de a se lasa fotografiata… e ceva nativ pentru ea. Scena si lumina reflectoarelor lucesc mai tare dupa aparitia ei misterioasa. VISUL MEU o incadreaza intr-o poveste de dragoste nemaivazuta, alaturi de magician.</p>
      </div>
                            <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:-300px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Magic-Aly/1408354842777607?fref=ts"><div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u1044"><!-- simple frame --></div></a>

      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu396"><!-- group -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Container invi clearfix grpelem" id="u389"><!-- group -->
     <div class="museBGSize grpelem" id="u399"><!-- simple frame --></div>
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu400-4"><!-- column -->
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u400-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>AN'TONIKA</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u402-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>ALL-IN-ONE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u401-4"><!-- content -->
          <p>Stie tot! face tot! iar personalitatea ei tonica o face de neinlocuit in echipa!<br/>Puterea ei o face sa ramana in picioare oricate responsabilitati i-ai atribuit:<br/>- backstage, artist, costume, make-up… orice!</p>
      </div>
                <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:-300px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/antonela.knigge?fref=ts"><div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u1044"><!-- simple frame --></div></a>

      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu403"><!-- group -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
        <div class="Container invi clearfix grpelem" id="u391"><!-- group -->
         <div class="museBGSize grpelem" id="u407"><!-- simple frame --></div>
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu407-4"><!-- column -->
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u407-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>VANESSA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u409-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>ASISTENTA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u408-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>Prea pasionata de dans sportiv si street dance… a reusit sa faca performanta. Rasplata stand in diverse cupe si premii obtinute la Campionatele Nationale.<br/>In VISUL MEU are rolul de a levita si de a se lasa taiata in 3, de un spectator.</p>
          </div>
                                <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:-300px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/magicvanessa?fref=ts"><div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u1044"><!-- simple frame --></div></a>

          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu410"><!-- group -->
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Container invi clearfix grpelem" id="u391"><!-- group -->
         <div class="museBGSize grpelem" id="u406"><!-- simple frame --></div>
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu407-4"><!-- column -->
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u407-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>ROBO</p>
          </div>
                                <a style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:-300px;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/CristianNovac?fref=ts"><div class="rounded-corners grpelem" id="u1044"><!-- simple frame --></div></a>

          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u409-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>DANSATOR</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u408-4"><!-- content -->
           <p>Recunoscut a fi cel mai original dansator de Electric Boogie, datorita inventarii unui stil propriu. Acest stil sincronizeaza perfect miscarile cu sistemele de lumini pe care s-i le construieste singur.  Mai mult are abilitatea de a juca orice rol pe care Lorenzo il gaseste.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu410"><!-- group -->
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Link is broken? question is uncelar. "Want to change div" in what ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735512/replace-div-content-onclick

Comment: do you want show and hide functionalit

Comment: sorry the link is promotii-timisoara.com/magicmarketing

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do something like this. You can find lots of implementations in various libraries. Even Bootstrap has this functionality built into it.

That being said, I just cooked something custom up really quickly for you to view and play with. See the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vpw7kkt/) example and click the red circles to see how they change the content below.

HTML:

```
<ul class="circles">
  <li class="circle active" data-toggle="1"></li>
  <li class="circle" data-toggle="2"></li>
  <li class="circle" data-toggle="3"></li>
  <li class="circle" data-toggle="4"></li>
  <li class="circle" data-toggle="5"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="boxes">
  <li class="box active" data-toggled-by="1">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="box" data-toggled-by="2">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="box" data-toggled-by="3">
    <h1>Box 3</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="box" data-toggled-by="4">
    <h1>Box 4</h1>
  </li>
  <li class="box" data-toggled-by="5">
    <h1>Box 5</h1>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.circle:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

li.circle.active {
  border-color: black;
}

li.box {
  width: 90%;
  display: none;
  background: white;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}

li.box.active {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('.circle').click(function() {
    // De-activate previously active circle
    $('.circle.active').removeClass('active');

    // Activate clicked circle
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Get toggle ID of clicked circle
    var toggleId = $(this).data('toggle');

    // De-activate previously active box
    $('.box.active').removeClass('active');

    // Activate box with corresponding toggle ID
    $('.box[data-toggled-by="' + toggleId + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```