# move from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Currently I have only contents of `div=content2` visible on my screen. It has some content and a button. All other div's content are not visible (the display style of other div's are set to none) Now when I click on the button I want the content of only `div=ContentXYZ` to be displayed. Basically I want to move from current div content to a different div content.

I don't want anything from my current screen to be visible I just want all the contents of another div to be displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery show and hide div on mouse click (animate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638990/jquery-show-and-hide-div-on-mouse-click-animate)

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript you can alter the display properties of the divs. You could add a onclick function to your button where you change the styling of the div element.

```
function displayDiv(){
   document.getElementById("ContentXYZ").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working sample

**HTML**

```
<div id="content2">
    Content 2 goes here
    <button id="btn">Change Div</button>
</div>

<div id="contentXYZ" style="display:none;">
    Content XYZ goes here
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $('#content2').css('display','none');
    $('#contentXYZ').css('display','block');
});
```

more reference: [Replace Div Content onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735512/replace-div-content-onclick)

Comment: What is the div id contentXYZ is inside another div will it still work?

Comment: Yes it will, provided that the parent div is visible. else you'll need to do something like `$('#contentXYZ').css('display','block'); $('#contentXYZ').parents('div').css('display','block');` to set all it parents to visible.

Comment: Can I set the parent div's to invisible and still have a child div visible?

Answer (score 0):

The most angular way to do it would probably be with ng-class. ng-class conditionally applies a class for example:

```
ng-class="{'visible': div1}"
```

This would apply class visible if div1 is true.

Here is a working example:https://plnkr.co/edit/q2XzDbdxPMBFJUl5X7kl?p=preview