# How to load a different text when i click on element at the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am currently trying to build a website that would do all the functionalities I want in the same page instead of navigating in different pages. My page looks like that at the moment

[image]

I want when i click on a client from the sidebar to load a form in the place of the welcome user message that i have on the right of my sidebar. The form it would be the same for all the clients. Is it also possible to save the client that i will choose in a variable so i can use it later for receiveing elements from mysql Database?

Can anyone please quide me?
My source code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
    margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
    display: none;
    background-color: #262626;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Clients 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Client 1</a>
    <a href="#">Client 2</a>
    <a href="#">Client 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Welcome user</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>

<script>
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Regards

Comment: I'll give you the general idea. Put you whole html with the welcome message in a div. And set that div a .active class. When you click on one of the items inside your list do a $(".active").removeClass("active"). And add the .active class to what ever your li is linked to. By default those divs are display:none and you have one .active by default. The .active is display:block. Tada.

Comment: This is far too broad for SO's QA format IMO...

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are trying to develop an SPA(Single page application).

I would recommend you to use a Framework/Library like AngularJS or ReactJS & use there routing functionality to do implement this.

But If you are a beginner at JS.

You can do this by using the [Jquery's](https://jquery.com/) `onClick()` & `.html()` functions:

Please refer to this link:

[Replace Div Content onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735512/replace-div-content-onclick)